# Trying to update metadata and deploy using VS Code

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

Trying to learn VS Code. Im trying to update a permission set from VS code and deploying to Salesforce. I'm getting the error below. I am an admin but not sure why I can't deploy the change?

Anyone able to help?

[image]

[image]

Tried to edit on a permission set and got the following error
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any additional information about the error in the output or terminal tabs? The screenshot you've provided is also about a _custom permission_, which is different from a _permission set_.

Comment: Hey Derek, edited my post with some more information. Hope that helps. It says I dont have permission. I'm an administrator so not sure why I got that error?

Answer (score 0):

The error means exactly what it says. You cannot create Custom Permissions that are linked to a Salesforce license, which is what `isLicensed` does (and it is [documented to be read-only](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_custompermission.htm)).

I suspect you stumbled upon this while trying to do some experiments in deployment, which is unfortunate! Try updating a Page Layout or a Permission Set instead, which should give you a more straightforward learning experience.

Comment: I tried it on a permission set and got the error above. Does that mean only the ones in the list are deployable? I did try it on the Description but got the same error. I've yet to figure out on a page layout so will try that later.

Comment: @HulkBuster The changes you are making are not valid for the component types. Component XML is a strict, heavily validated format. Your second screenshot suggests that you added an element in the wrong place in the element tree.